# How do I decide my image has bright text or dark text? [LabVIEW]

Tags: image-processing, labview, text-extraction, image-thresholding

I'm working on a Text Extraction algorithm in which I need some assistance with thresholding an image. My development platform is LabVIEW 2015 and I'm using the "AutoBThreshold2.vi" from Vision Development Module 2015. I decided to go with Otsu's Algorithm for thresholding which is available as "Inter Class Variance" Method. Now, The problem is that I need to specify the "Look for" option to extract the text! Unfortunately, my input images will not always be same.

Kindly refer the attached source code along with sample images. My question is that Is there any way to find whether the image has Dark objects/Bright Objects on Dark Background/Bright Background? Meanwhile I'm also playing with Histogram to find out the BG & FG type!

[image: Text Extraction.vi]

[image: Get Optimal Plane.vi]

I'd really appreciate your help...

Comment: Basic internet security protocols for anyone using a computer: Do never, ever, download a zip file that a stranger offers in the internet.

Comment: background usually covers more pixels than text in any normal text document. just count the pixels

Comment: Please read [mcve]. The code needs to be copied *into* the question. Don’t post links to the code.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: How do you copy Labview code here? It would be just a screenshot.

Comment: @sweber: according to the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/labview/info) one should use a VI Snippet (whatever that is, I used Labview once, 20 years ago).

Comment: @AnderBiguri, Sorry! I didn't know that! Anyway I have replaced the link with VI snippets now!

Comment: @sweber, Thanks for suggesting the VI snippet idea!..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of NI forum, I'm able to solve this problem.

[image: Auto Thresholding]

https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Auto-Thresholding-an-image-for-text-extraction/m-p/3904533#M1108133

Answer (score 0):

Use `equalize vi` to solve this problem before thresholding, see below image to find it.

[image: equalize]